# Configuring Aptana FTP

Tags: ftp, aptana, data-synchronization

I wanted to configure Aptana to show files that I need to upload still. Is there any option like that in Aptana? Say I make changes to some files locally and test them. But sometimes I forget to FTP them to server. Is aptana smart enough to show that. I know that it would, if my server is an SVN repo with some plugins installed. But if the server is not a SVN or CVS repo?

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks,
Murali.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct decoration or sign on the files themselves, but in Aptana Studio 3, you could set up a [connection between your local project and the FTP server](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/FTP%2C+SFTP%2C+and+FTPS+Deployment) and then use `Deploy` > `Deploy App` to generate a smart sync dialog that shows which files are changed between the two end points.

Answer (score 0):

Aptana Studio has a ticket for this at http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-2951 which you could vote for.

-Max